# How to disable the hyperlinks in a div

Tags: javascript, html

How can I disable all hyperlinks in a div element? I don't want any active links in my div(editable).

Comment: ar you using a JavaScript library? (jQuery/Prototype etc)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
$("#myEditableDiv a").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Old and considered **bad**.

```
$("#myEditableDiv a").click(function(){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

First grab all the links.

```
var links = editable.getElementsByTagName('a'); // where "editable" is a var pointing to your div
```

Then set the onclick to false.

```
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  link.onclick = function() { return false; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can write a simple method as given below -

```
function disableLinksByElement(el) {
  if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
    if (typeof(el) == 'string') {
      el = document.getElementById(el);
    }
    var anchors = el.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0, end=anchors.length; i<end; i++) {
      anchors[i].onclick = function() {
        return false;
      };
    }
  }
}
```

//Call to function as

```
disableLinksByElement('mydiv');
```